# Django - Ask users to confirm change of PDF file

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I got a question regarding Fileupload. I got a form where users can upload PDFs and change the uploaded PDFs. When they change the PDF, I want to add a warning, asking them to confirm the PDF change. Any idea what's the best way of doing it?

Right now, I'm trying to solve it with JS in my HTML, like so:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input class="deleter" type="submit" value="Delete">
    {% include "some_html.html" %}
  </form>
<script>
  // Add event listener to change button
  function confirmFileChange() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('id_file');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (fileInput.value) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the uploaded PDF?')) {
          fileInput.value = '';
        }
      }
    });
  }

  if (document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('Change: ') !== -1) {
    confirmFileChange();
  }
</script>
```

But this also displays the warning upon first upload, when the user isn't changing anything.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? Not sure if I quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you render your HTML in the django view with a command like `render(request, 'simple_upload.html')`.

The render command accept as third parameter a context object, where you can store information, that can be used in the template. You have to write in this context, if a PDF is already exists or not.

```
    context = { 'pdf_already_exists': True if pdfAlreadyExists() else False }
    render(request, 'simple_upload.html', context)
```

Now you can evaluate in the template if the PDF already exists.

```
    {% if pdf_already_exists %}
    <script>
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('id_file');
        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
          if (fileInput.value) {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to change the uploaded PDF?')) {
              fileInput.value = '';
            }
          }
        });
    </script>
    {% endif %}
```

The script is only rendered in the HTML when a PDF already exists, and the warning can not be displayed upon first upload, when the user isn't changing anything.

I hope that helps.